# VerticalOffset Double Animation on ListBox default ScrollViewer (WP8)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to do a VerticalOffset `DoubleAnimation` on the default `ScrollViewer` inside the `ListBox` control. I’ve seen a few examples for Windows 8 but have not found any for Windows Phone 8 and was not able to extrapolate how to do it in WP8, there were always incompatibilities.

From what I read the `VertcalOffsetProperty` is read only, but can be exposed and then used for the double animation.

What I’m trying to do is after user scrolls, `OnMouseUp` animates to align the current `ListBox` item to the top of the viewable area.

If someone could point me to an example or post a solution to do this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Are you trying to build something that "snaps" to the top, ... sort of?

Comment: @WiredPrairie Not snap but `slide` to the top.
The `ScrollIntoView` method looks terrible, so I'm trying to animated it.